# Why postfix doesn't follow From header from PHP mail();

Tags: php, debian, postfix, email

I have installed postfix with no config option.

I am trying to send email with php mail(); it works but it sends email with the default email of my dedicated server.

Are there anyway to tell postfix to follow the header set by mail function?

Thanks

### Code

```
$from='no-reply@mywebsite.com';
$fromname='my Website';
mail($mailto,$subject,$text,'From: ' . $fromname . ' <'.$from.'>');
```

Comment: what version of sendmail & php? What is sendmail_path configured as in php.ini?

Comment: it's postfix not sendemail. and php is 5.3.x

Comment: sorry which version of postfix, and what is the path configured (with any arguments?)

Comment: it's `/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i` O_O but i don't have sendmail lol. Thanks for any help

Comment: Can you post how you're calling the mail() method?

Comment: @dimmer: see post

Comment: Is safe mode enabled in php.ini?

Comment: nope it's off...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the -f and -r additional parameters to override the from header and return path respectively.

```
mail(
    $mailto,
    $subject,
    $text,
    "From: " . $fromname . " <".$from.">",
    "-f $from -r mybounceemail@example.com");
```

From the postfix sendmail man page:

```
   -f sender
     Set the envelope sender address. This is the address where delivery problems are sent to.  With  Postfix  versions  before  2.1,  the
     Errors-To: message header overrides the error return address.


   -r sender
     Set the envelope sender address. This is the address where delivery problems are sent to.  With  Postfix  versions  before  2.1,  the
     Errors-To: message header overrides the error return address.
```

Comment: thanks I will try. But Why should i set the -r?

Comment: It's best practice to set the return-path as well, only if you want to handle bounced messages separately than the regular postfix config.

By creatively setting the return path, you can even add intelligent bounce handling, see VERP:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_envelope_return_path

Answer (score 1):

If you have a million mail() and do not want to recode all your mail() functions... you can set in your php.ini the following... and it will universally set all you php mail() functions to use it.

```
sendmail_path = sendmail -t -f do_not_reply@your.com
```

Comment: thanks for the add.. but is there a reason on why the header arg doenst' work?

Comment: You need to also add the `-i` option to this or a single line with a `.` in int will flag end of input.